# TypeError: _client.ApolloClient is not a constructor getting error in jest case while mocking the apollo client

Tags: jestjs, apollo-client, babel-jest, lwc

I am trying to mock @apollo/client in my jest file with LWC component.But not able to mock it properly i guess.

here is the code below:

```js
import { ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';
const mockClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: appConfig['DEV'].EVENTS_API_URL,
        fetch: fetch,
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
        addTypename: false,
    }),
});

ApolloClient.setClient(mockClient);
jest.mock('@apollo/client', () => ({
    useApolloClient: () => null,
    makeVar: () =>
        jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(null);
        }),
    HttpLink: () =>
        jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return null;
        }),
}));
```

its should mock the @apollo/client properly but getting type error
After mocking like above getting a error
[image: test erro screenshot]